# Host connection Exception occurred while running test using "JMeter"

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMeter tool. I have recorded a test for my Web Fleet application developed in Java. I ran the test after recording some steps. I received below exception in Response data [View Results Tree]. Anybody help me.

org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://maps.google.com refused

Answer (score 0):

You're testing **your** web application, not Google Maps, right? I would recommend to exclude maps.google.com from your recorded script.

Just re-record your test case setting ["Include and Exclude Filter Pattern"](http://blazemeter.com/blog/blazemeters-chrome-extension-record-and-edit-jmeter-script-without-using-jmeter) to ignore Google Maps and whatever external hosts to narrow requests down to only your application host(s).